# Find and Kill PID using Port in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, ubuntu

I've been working with rails, and occasionally my server slips into the background and I have to kill it manually. To do this I have been using the following commands.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep port_number
sudo -9 PID
```

Is there a way to do this in a single line so that I can alias it? Or even a way to do it without me having to copy the PID so that I can put it in a script?

Comment: can you show the output of the first command?

Comment: http://www.serverschool.com/server-configuration/listening-for-programs-on-server-ports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep port_number | tail -c 23 | sed -e 's/\s*\(.*\)/\1/g' -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/g'`
```

I do have to say, though, that is rather dangerous because it'd kill partial matches (Let's say you have something on port 8081 and you run this with 81, it'd kill the item on 8081 if that was the first listing in netstat)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep ":16667 " | sed -n 's@.* \([0-9]*\)/ruby.*@kill \1@p' | sudo sh
```

Only kills ruby processes listening on that exact port.